# Compling Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: qt

I installed the Qt's online installer available with MSVC compiler. When I tried to compile my project, it didn't detect any of the kits. Rather showed the error No kits found. Something like problem configuring make.

To run it successfully do we need to install Visual Studio express as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSVC builds of Qt you need Visual C++ compiler installed separately (Windows SDK before version 8 contained the C++ compiler, so that might be an alternative to installing Visual Studio - but if you go this path check the MSDN to verify what C++ compiler version is in what SDK, because the version must match with the one Qt is built with).
Only the MinGW built of Qt is an package that contains an compiler too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add compiler https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-tool-chains.html, Qt version https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-project-qmake.html and make a "kit" of them http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-targets.html in QtCreator